# How to find the Cortana shortcut created by Windows to Launch Anaconda and Activate Env?

Tags: windows-10, anaconda, cortana

I reinstalled Miniconda on a new machine and installed 64-bit and 32-bit versions. Now, when I type in Cortana, 'anaconda' I get offered an option which I understand is a conda environment, but I can't recreate this behavior. (See my other post, [How can I launch Miniconda and activate an environment at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57414388/how-can-i-launch-miniconda-and-activate-an-environment-at-the-same-time))

[image]

```
(qb) C:\Users\myhome>conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                     C:\Users\myhome\Miniconda3_32
qb                    *  C:\Users\myhome\Miniconda3_32\envs\qb
                         C:\Users\myhome\Miniconda3_64-4.5.4
                         C:\Users\myhome\Miniconda3_64-4.5.4\envs\rb
```

[Note, this also lists environments from my 64-bit installation]

And, if I 'deactivate' the environment, I don't fall back to `(base)`. That seems weird to me,

```
(qb) C:\Users\myhome>conda deactivate
C:\myhome\pear>
```

Is there a way to duplicate this behavior by learning what Cortana is doing and  editing some file in Windows?

---

Honestly. This is really weird result. I'm not disorganized, and I've installed Anaconda on three work machines to deploy a few Python Scripts. I have no idea what I did to get this result that I now can't recreate. I'm not even tinkering with conda env's to any great extent. I was installing everything to base until: [Why would conda package installation and update clobber conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57340661/why-would-conda-package-installation-and-update-clobber-conda). It just happened that Cortana suggests this env.

Comment: You have a shortcut somewhere for that environment most likely.  If you click the *Open file location* option it should show you where.

Comment: That worked. It was located in the Start Menu (`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (32-bit)`). I found the file, copied it and made the corrections as noted in the original post on the same topic. I will change the question so this will become the correct answer. TX